# Show that: $ \lim_{n}\int_{E}{g_n(t)d\mu(t)}=\int_{E}{\langle x^*,f_{\infty}(t) \rangle d\mu(t)} $

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $X$ be a Banach space, the associated dual space is denoted by $X^*$ and the usual duality between $X$ and $X^*$ by $\langle.,.\rangle$.

Let $\{f_n\}_n$ be a uniformly integrable subset of  $\mathcal{L}_{X}^{1}$ (space of all Bochner integrable functions from  $E$ into $X$) converges weakly to some $f_{\infty} \in\mathcal{L}_{X}^{1}$.

Let $x^*\in X^*$, we suppose that the sequence of integrable function $\{g_n\}$, defined by : $g_n=\langle x^*,f_n\rangle$, is uniformly integrable.

Show that:
$$
\lim_{n}\int_{E}{g_n(t)d\mu(t)}=\int_{E}{\langle x^*,f_{\infty}(t) \rangle d\mu(t)}
$$

An idea please.

Comment: Idea: Subtract the right-hand side from the equation you want to show. Then use the triangle inequality.

Comment: I did not understand sir, you can write the first step of the proof